# QGIS DB Manager Import layer/file Oracle not working - Error 8 Loading of the layer failed

Tags: qgis, import, oracle-dbms

QGIS 2.12.0 - DB Manager 0.1.20 - Windows 7 - Oracle 11g 11.2.0.3.0

Import vector layer

Shapefile as well as a layer (vector) and with every possible combinations of settings, the results are the same. It also happens with a previously exported table (as shp) from same db/schema:

```
Error 8
Loading of the layer "myschema"."mytable" failed
```

An inspection of the "loaded" table indicates that only the 'geom' column was created (no other columns where created), it is however of UNKNOWN geometry type and the table is empty.

user_sdo_geom_metadata record was created correctly.

All other operations within DB Manager on existing tables work correctly.

Is there perhaps another way of loading existing vector layers onto Oracle (pyQGIS?)?

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been reported 2 years ago, thug life oracle .. https://issues.qgis.org/issues/14026

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one can help.

Firstly connect to Oracle via GeoServer and create a table in GeoServer. Publish this layer with WFS, add WFS to QGIS and add geometry to this layer save your edits.

In DB Manager create a blank table with geometry like created in GeoServer.

And run QSL at below table who created in QGİS; "in QGIS adding a table without geometry is not editable for this problem copying geometry from another table will make it editable".

```
insert into ""TablenamecreatedinQGis"(id, geom) select 1, geom from ""TablenamecreatedinGeoserver
```

after, this you can import your layer to on this table.